# ArcMap and attribute table

Tags: arcgis, geoserver, arcmap

I am wondering how you can save multiple data for one point feature in ArcMap?

For example, I have a shape-file with point features, the data that needs to be included for each point feature consists of different years (2007, 2008, 2009 and 2010). Each year includes data such as total number of students, enrollments, est. How can I save this data in arcMap for each specific point feature?

I need to be able to save all data for individual point features, from which I can load into Geoserver, and when a point feature is selected in OpenLayers (Geoserver), all the (yearly) data will be displayed.

So far I have tried joining the data in arcmap, but when served up in GeoServer, only the year 2007 is displayed when a point feature is selected, and the rest of the years are not displayed (happens for all point features).

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Why not have a column for each year? That is the classic way of sharing geometry.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into creating a [One to Many](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/37544) join in ArcMap or see whether this is possible in Geoserver.

Answer (score 0):

join your data and export it.. you will have a NEW shapefile for all the years together ..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the locations of the points for all of the years are the same. If that is the case, then the "Spatial Join" tool within ArcMap is going to help you. The only annoying part when using that tool is that you will have to run it 3 separate times as you can only join two files at a time.

Another thing that helps with that tool is to that provide a numerical value for the search radius under "match option".

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple. Please follow the following steps
Scenario: Let's consider we are sampling the water bore locations. So water source location will be the same. We will take samples for 5 conductive years.I am considering the Point fixed with changing years results.
1. Join all layers in arcmap. 
2. Export this joined layer.
3. Again add in ArcMap.
4. Give unique symbology on the basis of Years. such as 2005, 2006,2007, 2008 etc.
5. Each colour will categorize the yearly basis results.
6. Import this layer in Geo Server.
7. Get this layer in your application.
8. Click on any point and Get the all year results.

Hope this is the answer.